# Facebook Access Token Refresh

Tags: facebook

To post to Facebook on behalf of a person, an app has to gain a long-lasting token in a process that involves the person authenticating themselves and giving permission to post.

[Facebook's token expiration](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension)  documentation says:

> These tokens will be refreshed once per day when **the person using your
>   app makes a request to Facebook's servers**. If no requests are made,
>   the token will expire after about 60 days and the person will have to
>   go through the login flow again to get a new token.

This could mean:

1. The person who authorised the token visits Facebook's servers. *So the token exists as long as the person is a regular Facebook user.*
2. The app (using the token) visits Facebook's servers. *So the token exists as long as it is regularly used.*

Which is it? And if it is option 2, can the app make a idempotent request to Facebook's servers to keep the token alive past 60 days?

Comment: Since what you quoted refers to native mobile apps, I would assume it means the user has to make an API request using your app.